# Dividing multiple numbers in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to divide multiple numbers in a for loop, output is incorrect answer

Created a variable for the answer, in each for loop it will make answer equal to the previous loops answer divided by the integer from the for loops list.

```
def div(x):
    ans = 0
    for i in x:
        ans = ans / int(i)

b = int(input("How many numbers would you like to " + opt + "?"))
c = range(0,b)
d = list()
for i in c:
    d.append(input("What number would you like to " + opt + "?"))
print(div(d))
```

If 3 numbers are input to the list (d). I want to divide these 3 numbers and make the variable (ans) equal to the quotient

Example:
Input 3 numbers - 200, 10, 2

Result: 10

Actual Results from script: 0.0

Comment: In `div` you start with `ans = 0` and zero divided by anything non-zero is zero. And it isn't returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

First, our function does not return a value. You can fix this by adding `return ans` at the end of the function.

Second, if you start with `ans = 0`, dividing `ans` will only get you more zeros.

Here's one solutions, using a placeholder to skip over the solution:

```
def div(x):
    ans = None
    for i in x:
        if ans is None:
            ans = i
        else:
            ans = ans / int(i)
    return ans
```

Here's a slightly more elegant alternative, using an [arbitrary argument list](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

```
def div(init, *divisors):
    ans = init
    for x in divisors:
        ans /= x # divide and assign together
    return ans

div(100, 10, 2) # returns 5
div(*[100, 10, 2]) # returns 5
```

By declaring a function parameter with `*`, any extra parameters given will be packed into it as a list. You can then pass arguments to it without putting them in a list, or you can use another `*` to unpack the list into multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks again- and sorry for the noob question

Comment: Don't worry making mistakes: we all have to start somewhere, and nobody gets everything perfect on the first try. Keep going, and you'll get there!

Answer (score 0):

The `div` function doesn't actually return anything, so it should be printing `None` ?

this should fix your problem:

```
def div(x):
    ans = 0
    for i in x:
       ans = ans / i

    return ans
```